# How to prevent processing files twice with Spark DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I'm processing some S3 TSV to S3 Parquet using AWS Glue.  Due to non-UTF-8 incoming files I am forced to use DataFrames instead of DynamicFrames to process my data (it's a known issue with no workaounds that DynamicFrames fail completely with any non-UTF8 characters).  This also seems to mean that I cannot use Job Bookmarks in Glue to keep track of which S3 TSV files I have already processed.

My code looks like this:

```py
# pylint: skip-file
# flake8: noqa
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

# @params: [JOB_NAME, s3target]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 's3target', 's3source'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# Define massive list of fields in the schema
fields = [
    StructField("accept_language", StringType(), True),
    StructField("browser", LongType(), True),
    .... huge list ...
    StructField("yearly_visitor", ShortType(), True),
    StructField("zip", StringType(), True)
]

schema = StructType(fields)

# Read in data using Spark DataFrame and not an AWS Glue DynamicFrame to avoid issues with non-UTF8 characters
df0 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quote", "\"").option("delimiter", u'\u0009').option("charset", 'utf-8').schema(schema).load(args['s3source'] + "/*.tsv.gz")

# Remove all rows that are entirely nulls
df1 = df0.dropna(how = 'all')

# Generate a partitioning column
df2 = df1.withColumn('date', df1.date_time.cast('date'))

# Write out in parquet format, partitioned by date, to the S3 location specified in the arguments
ds2 = df2.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("date").mode("append").save(args['s3target'])

job.commit()
```

My question is - without job bookmarks each time this runs it processes the same s3 files over and over again.  How can I move processed files in the source s3 bucket to a subfolder or something, or otherwise avoid double processing the files?

I'm not sure what the trick is here, with Spark being a parallel system, and not really even knowing what the files are.  I guess I could create a second Glue job with the Python Shell job type and delete the incoming files immediately after, but even then I'm not sure which files to delete, etc.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Have you already took a look in S3 data life cycle? Maybe you could define a expiration time and after, S3 will delete or move your file to glacier or other s3 storage layers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html

Comment: I have, however you couldn't guarantee you process the file only once, depending on run rate.  Sometimes I run the job a few times a day when there's issues.  I already use lifecycle rules to glaciate old input files.

Comment: Is your data partitioned by time so that the folder you read from has subfolders with a naming convention of "dt=20190101" (which contains all data from the first of January of 2019) for example? Then you can transform the partitions one by one on a daily basis.

Comment: No unfortunately the files are dumped hourly into an s3 bucket by a third party.

Comment: Note, entire solution has been open sourced: https://github.com/HealthEngineAU/adobe-analytics-data-lake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark the processed files out of the input source prefix, you'll have to use `boto3` (or awscli directly) to move the files or delete them.

To identify which files to process, you can proceed in 2 different ways:

- resolve your file glob `args['s3source'] + "/*.tsv.gz"` using boto3 with `s3client.list_objects()` before using spark. 
  You can provide an array of resolved files instead of a glob to `spark.read.load`.

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

# get all the available files
# Note: if you expect a lot of files, you need to iterate on the pages of results

response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=your_bucket_name,Prefix=your_path_prefix)
files=['s3://'+your_bucket_name+obj['Key'] for obj in response['Contents'] if obj.endswith('tsv.gz')]

 ... initialize your job as before ...

df0 = df0 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quote", "\"").option("delimiter", u'\u0009').option("charset", 'utf-8').schema(schema).load(files)

 ... do your work as before ...
```

- use the fact that spark keeps track of all its input files to post-process them after a successful save:

```py
 ... process your files with pyspark as before...

# retrieve the tracked files from the initial DataFrame
# you need to access the java RDD instances to get to the partitions information
# The file URIs will be in the following format: u's3://mybucket/mypath/myfile.tsv.gz'

files = [] 
for p in df0.rdd._jrdd.partitions(): 
    files.append([f.filePath() for f in p.files().array()])
```

Once you have the file list, deleting, renaming or adding them to a metadata store to filter them out on the next job is pretty straightforward.

For example, to delete them:

```py
# initialize a S3 client if not already done
from urlparse import urlparse # python 2
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

# do what you want with the uris, for example delete them
for uri in files:
   parsed = urlparse(uri)
   client.delete_object(Bucket=parsed.netloc, Key=parsed.path)
```

Comment: This looks like good stuff...give me a few days to give me a chance to try it :)

Comment: I'm showing my lack of familiarity with Spark & Python here, but I can't figure out this issue:

`File "script_2019-04-24-08-08-21.py", line 731, in <module>
files = [f.filePath() for f in p.files().array() for p in df0.rdd._jrdd.partitions()]
NameError: name 'p' is not defined`

Comment: do you have your `df0` DataFrame defined at this point in the code ? The `files = ...` line needs to happen after your processing, just before the `job.commit()`

Comment: Yeah I do - exactly where you suggest.  I'm firing up a dev endpoint atm to have a play with it.

Comment: This construct works:

`files2 = []
for p in df0.rdd._jrdd.partitions():    files2.append([f.filePath() for f in p.files().array()])`

Is it a python 2 vs 3 thing?

Comment: Possibly. my code examples are for python 3. Are you on python 2 ?

Comment: Yep, Glue is python2 only.  I had to change your urlparse import back to python 2 as well...

Answer (score 1):

If you're not concerned about processing the same source files again (vis a vis the time constraints) and your use case is to not have duplicated data in the destination, you may consider updating the save mode to "Overwrite" when writing the dataframe

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I used for one of our ETL process developed over AWS glue was to first list and move the files in s3 using boto3 API to a "WORK" folder. This process should not take any time as you are only changing the s3 object name rather than any physical movement.

Once the above step is done you can use the "WORK" folder as input for your SPARK dataFrame while new files can keep getting pushed to your other s3 folder.

I am not sure about your use case,but we used current system datetime to create the "WORK" folder so that we can investigate or rerun any files if we find any issue with the process or data that we loaded after few days.

Answer (score 0):

Final working code:

```
# pylint: skip-file
# flake8: noqa
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
import boto3
from urlparse import urlparse

# Read arguments
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 's3target', 's3source'])

# Initialise boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

# Get all the available files
response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket = "xxx")
files = [ "s3://xxx/" + obj['Key'] for obj in response['Contents'] if obj['Key'].endswith('.tsv.gz') ]

# Initialise the glue job
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# Define massive list of fields in the schema
fields = [
    StructField("accept_language", StringType(), True),
    StructField("browser", LongType(), True),
    .... huge list ...
    StructField("yearly_visitor", ShortType(), True),
    StructField("zip", StringType(), True)
]

schema = StructType(fields)

# Read in data using Spark DataFrame and not an AWS Glue DynamicFrame to avoid issues with non-UTF8 characters
df0 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quote", "\"").option("delimiter", u'\u0009').option("charset", 'utf-8').schema(schema).load(files)

# Remove all rows that are entirely nulls
df1 = df0.dropna(how = 'all')

# Generate a partitioning column
df2 = df1.withColumn('date', df1.date_time.cast('date'))

# Write out in parquet format, partitioned by date, to the S3 location specified in the arguments
ds2 = df2.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("date").mode("append").save(args['s3target'])

# retrieve the tracked files from the initial DataFrame
# you need to access the java RDD instances to get to the partitions information
# The file URIs will be in the following format: u's3://mybucket/mypath/myfile.tsv.gz'
files = []
for p in df0.rdd._jrdd.partitions():
    files.extend([f.filePath() for f in p.files().array()])

# Move files to the processed folder
for uri in files:
   parsed = urlparse(uri)
   client.copy_object(CopySource = {'Bucket': parsed.netloc, 'Key': parsed.path.lstrip('/')}, Bucket = parsed.netloc, Key = 'processed' + parsed.path)
   client.delete_object(Bucket = parsed.netloc, Key = parsed.path.lstrip('/'))

job.commit()
```